# MVC 4 application does not work in windows 10 (IIS 10)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-10, iis-10

I upgraded to windows 10. After that my MVC 4 application stopped working. I created virtual directory in IIS(from VS 2015 right click project-->Go to prperties-->Go to Web tab-->From server section, select Local IIS from dropdown-->click on create cirtual directory button). Now when I browse that directory, it lists all files under directory in browser. Rather it should load view from default controller. If I writer controller name explicitly, then I am getting 4.4 error.

Is there any change in configuration from windows 7 to windows 10..?

Comment: Did you do an upgrade, or a fresh install? What .NET version is the application pool running as?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below snippet in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

or try installing this hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980368

Comment: The hotfix is not applicable to IIS version 10 (which comes with windows 10, and server 2016). runAllManaged is highly advised against, and is not a fix but a bandaid to force loading of all modules (namely the UrlRoutingModule from .net GAC). 
I for one have tried all of the above and none of it has made IIS properly pick up url routing.